# How to subtract "Text B" from "Text A" given that "Text B" is a subset of "Text A"?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe (dataframe A) where every row contains some text:

```
df_A = structure(list(Text = c("To this end, we strongly support the Commission in its determination to promote the renewed Lisbon Strategy and we encourage national governments to show their determination in this regard by implementing structural reforms in Europe. In fact, incoming information since the last Governing Council meeting indicates a more protracted weakness of the euro area economy, the persistence of prominent downside risks and muted inflationary pressures. This is the type of text that I would like to cancel and keep only the other one. This is reflected in the new staff projections, which show a further downgrade of the inflation outlook.", 
"To this end, we strongly support the Commission in its determination to promote the renewed Lisbon Strategy and we encourage national governments to show their determination in this regard by implementing structural reforms in Europe. There are super skilled people in SO who will hopefully help me sort this out. In fact, incoming information since the last Governing Council meeting indicates a more protracted weakness of the euro area economy, the persistence of prominent downside risks and muted inflationary pressures. This is reflected in the new staff projections, which show a further downgrade of the inflation outlook.", 
"To this end, we strongly support the Commission in its determination to promote the renewed Lisbon Strategy and we encourage national governments to show their determination in this regard by implementing structural reforms in Europe. I would really like to remove this bit and I hope that SE will sort it out. In fact, incoming information since the last Governing Council meeting indicates a more protracted weakness of the euro area economy, the persistence of prominent downside risks and muted inflationary pressures. This is reflected in the new staff projections, which show a further downgrade of the inflation outlook."
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I then have another dataframe (dataframe B) which I extracted from the dataframe A above:

```
df_B = structure(list(Text = c("This is the type of text that I would like to cancel and keep only the other one.", 
"There are super skilled people in SO who will hopefully help me sort this out.", 
"I would really like to remove this bit and I hope that SE will sort it out."
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

What I would like to do is substracting the text in dataframe B from the text in dataframe A to gain dataframe C:

```
# df_C = df_A - df_B

[[1]]"To this end, we strongly support the Commission in its determination to promote the renewed Lisbon Strategy and we encourage national governments to show their determination in this regard by implementing structural reforms in Europe. In fact, incoming information since the last Governing Council meeting indicates a more protracted weakness of the euro area economy, the persistence of prominent downside risks and muted inflationary pressures. This is reflected in the new staff projections, which show a further downgrade of the inflation outlook."

[[2]] "To this end, we strongly support the Commission in its determination to promote the renewed Lisbon Strategy and we encourage national governments to show their determination in this regard by implementing structural reforms in Europe. In fact, incoming information since the last Governing Council meeting indicates a more protracted weakness of the euro area economy, the persistence of prominent downside risks and muted inflationary pressures. This is reflected in the new staff projections, which show a further downgrade of the inflation outlook."
 
[[3]] "To this end, we strongly support the Commission in its determination to promote the renewed Lisbon Strategy and we encourage national governments to show their determination in this regard by implementing structural reforms in Europe. In fact, incoming information since the last Governing Council meeting indicates a more protracted weakness of the euro area economy, the persistence of prominent downside risks and muted inflationary pressures. This is reflected in the new staff projections, which show a further downgrade of the inflation outlook."
```

Can anyone help me do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R does not offer string substitution that is vectorized on pattern. You can do something like:

```
mapply(
  function(x,y) gsub(y, "", x, fixed = TRUE),
  x = df_A$Text,
  y = df_B$Text,
  USE.NAMES = FALSE
)

[1] "To this end, we strongly support the Commission in its determination to promote the renewed Lisbon Strategy and we encourage national governments to show their determination in this regard by implementing structural reforms in Europe. In fact, incoming information since the last Governing Council meeting indicates a more protracted weakness of the euro area economy, the persistence of prominent downside risks and muted inflationary pressures.  This is reflected in the new staff projections, which show a further downgrade of the inflation outlook."
[2] "To this end, we strongly support the Commission in its determination to promote the renewed Lisbon Strategy and we encourage national governments to show their determination in this regard by implementing structural reforms in Europe.  In fact, incoming information since the last Governing Council meeting indicates a more protracted weakness of the euro area economy, the persistence of prominent downside risks and muted inflationary pressures. This is reflected in the new staff projections, which show a further downgrade of the inflation outlook."
[3] "To this end, we strongly support the Commission in its determination to promote the renewed Lisbon Strategy and we encourage national governments to show their determination in this regard by implementing structural reforms in Europe.  In fact, incoming information since the last Governing Council meeting indicates a more protracted weakness of the euro area economy, the persistence of prominent downside risks and muted inflationary pressures. This is reflected in the new staff projections, which show a further downgrade of the inflation outlook."
```

the `stringr` package, which is basically an alternate interface for the `stringi` package, offers fast vectorized string substitution and some handy utility functions.:

```
stringr::str_remove(df_A$Text, df_B$Text)
[1] "To this end, we strongly support the Commission in its determination to promote the renewed Lisbon Strategy and we encourage national governments to show their determination in this regard by implementing structural reforms in Europe. In fact, incoming information since the last Governing Council meeting indicates a more protracted weakness of the euro area economy, the persistence of prominent downside risks and muted inflationary pressures.  This is reflected in the new staff projections, which show a further downgrade of the inflation outlook."
[2] "To this end, we strongly support the Commission in its determination to promote the renewed Lisbon Strategy and we encourage national governments to show their determination in this regard by implementing structural reforms in Europe.  In fact, incoming information since the last Governing Council meeting indicates a more protracted weakness of the euro area economy, the persistence of prominent downside risks and muted inflationary pressures. This is reflected in the new staff projections, which show a further downgrade of the inflation outlook."
[3] "To this end, we strongly support the Commission in its determination to promote the renewed Lisbon Strategy and we encourage national governments to show their determination in this regard by implementing structural reforms in Europe.  In fact, incoming information since the last Governing Council meeting indicates a more protracted weakness of the euro area economy, the persistence of prominent downside risks and muted inflationary pressures. This is reflected in the new staff projections, which show a further downgrade of the inflation outlook."
```